# Flex Date related Functions

Tags: apache-flex

I need to calculate a start date as 01- 01- 2013 when my end date is 31-12-2012 using Flex Date Functions'.

Comment: Generally speaking; the start date is usually before the end date.  You may want to edit your question to elaborate on the specific algorithm you want to perform.  It is not obvious to me based on the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add a certain amount of days (1 in your example) to an existing date? You can do this by creating a new date based on the time of the other date + the difference:

Example:

```
var numMillisecondsInOneDay:Number = 24*60*60*1000;
var startDate:Date = new Date(endDate.getTime() + numMillisecondsInOneDay);
```

FYI: The [AS3Commons-Lang](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/index.html) project contains a DateUtils class that offers a set of Date manipulation methods.

Comment: It's actually easier to just add 1 to the day property of the date than do all that multiplication junk. http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/05/working-with-dates-in-as3.html